# Odd behaviour with interface typehints and inheritance

Tags: php, php-7

Here's the situation I have:

```
interface IFoo {}

class FooImplementation implements IFoo {
    public $someProperty;
}

class SomeParentClass {
    public function someMethod(Ifoo $someParam) {...}
}

class SomeChildClass extends SomeParentClass {
    public function someMethod(FooImplementation $someParam) {
         // do something with someProperty from $someParam
    }
}
```

When trying to run the `someMethod` from the `SomeChildClass` I get a warning saying that

```
Declaration of SomeChildClass::someMethod should be compatible with SomeParentClass::someMethod
```

However, I do think they are compatible...

I have a parent class that specifies it needs an object adhering to an interface as parameter, and in it's child class, I'm using a class that implements said interface. Therefor, to me, it is strange that is throws that warning,

While I do understand that when doing a straight up compare in classnames, Ifoo is different than FooImplementation. I feel like what I'm trying to do is correct, unless I'm completely overlooking something here.

EDIT: I understand this is due to PHP not supporting covariance... A follow-up question, in the child class, I need to do something with with a property on the `FooImplementation` class that is not defined in the interface. How would I best go about doing so?

Comment: Currently in PHP, you can't change the typehint when overriding a parents method.

Comment: This is called contravariance and PHP does not support it yet

Comment: @apokryfos you say, does not support it yet, does that mean that it is something that will be supported down the road?

Comment: This is breaking Liskov substitution either way, even if it was supported. If you have a function type hinting for `SomeParentClass`, and you pass it an instance of `SomeChildClass`, it would be expected that its `someMethod` would accept any instance of `IFoo`. But it does not, it in fact only accept instances of `FooImplementation`, so your type system is bust.

Comment: Actually I was wrong. This is covariance and it is not going to be supported. It is not type safe. The RFC is https://wiki.php.net/rfc/covariant-returns-and-contravariant-parameters

Comment: @deceze fair enough, looks like I'll need to read up on the Liskov substitution principle a bit. It does make sense though.